# Commerical delayed stock quote feed that is redistributable?

Tags: equities, quote

I'm looking for a commercial delayed quote feed that will allow us to distribute delayed US stock market quotes to the public (ie. that will allow us to display US delayed quotes on the Internet).  We are only interested in stocks listed on the NYSE, AMEX, and NASDAQ. The best that I could find were Xignite and BarChartMarketData.  Virtually all other companies that I found only supply data for individual use or use inside a company, but not for the public.

We are targeting delayed data because the redistribution fees the stock exchanges charge us are cheaper for delayed US market data: http://www.barchartmarketdata.com/solutions_datafeed_exchfees.php

BATS is not an option for us because my boss wants data from NYSE, AMEX, and NASDAQ.  Yahoo and Google Finance data are not an option either because that data cannot be redistributed to the public.

I've already read several stackexchange questions on this but neither have answers to a commerical delayed market data feed that can be redistributed.  Are Xignite and BarChartMarketData the only options out there?  Who else has a website or application that is display delayed quotes and which vendor are you using?

Comment: I thought commercial redistribution was basically the same regardless of vendor since they supposedly pay the same amount to the exchange. I can't imagine pricing would be too different. By the way, the NYSE Amex [has been renamed NYSE MKT](http://www.nyse.com/press/1336646911531.html).

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, and for what I've seen so far, Xignite seems to be the best option. I am currently taking a look at the [SEC data](http://www.sec.gov/info/edgar.shtml), which is great for historical data, and freely accesible. However, I am not really sure whether this data can be used for commercial purposes. Have you found any other provider?

Comment: The OP is asking about market data; EDGAR only lists earnings statements.

Comment: Did you find any better providers?